# ngRoute: Template temporal durante 5 segundos al acceder a una ruta con id

Tags: javascript, angularjs

¿Cómo puedo hacer que un template se muestre temporalmente durante 5 segundos al acceder a una ruta especifica con id -La ruta con id ya tiene su propio template-, luego de los 5 segundos que se muestre el template que debió mostrarse originalmente en la ruta? Eh buscado en todas partes y no eh encontrado nada al respecto. :(

Esto es un ejemplo de como tengo las rutas:

```js
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
      .when('/',{
        redirectTo: '/news'
      })
      .when('/news',{
        templateUrl: 'html/news.html',
        controller: 'newsCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'news',
        title: 'Noticias'
      })
      .when('/news/:id',{
        templateUrl: 'html/article.html',
        controller: 'articleCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'article',
        title: 'Artículo'          
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/error404'
      });
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
  }]);
```

Este código hace que el template se muestre en cierto tiempo, talvez se podría hacer con algo así, no?

```js
resolve: {
      delay: function($q,$timeout){
        var delay = $q.defer();
        $timeout(delay.resolve, 250);
        return delay.promise;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Los templates se cargan por vista y una vez cargados no pueden cambiarse. Lo que quieres se puede lograr dentro de una sola vista, reemplazando su contenido al transcurrir cierto tiempo pero sin nada de código y sin saber que sistema de rutas estás usando es imposible ayudarte.

Comment: @devconcept Gracias por comentar. Actualice la pregunta con unos ejemplos, talvez ahora puedas ayudarme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si entendí correctamente tu quieres algo como esto

```
url -> 0s -> plantilla temporal -> 5s -> plantilla final
```

Esto no es posible ni cambiando la plantilla usando `templateUrl: function` ni usando `resolve`, la razón es la siguiente:

1. Las opciones `template` o `templateUrl` cuando la usas con una función en lugar de un `string` esperan que le devuelvas contenido (`string`), no una promesa (`$timeout`)

   ```
   .when('/news',{
       templateUrl: function() {
           // Siempre debes retornar un string
           return 'html/news.html';
       }
   })
   ```

   > `template`: plantilla html en forma de string, o una función que retorne una plantilla html como un string que deberá ser usada por las directivas `ngView` o `ngInclude`.
2. Usando un `resolve` puedes devolver una promesa pero esto implica que:

   - Cuando está pendiente la página está esperando y no navega
   - Cuando se resuelve la página navega hacia el `template` o `templateUrl` que configuraste y no permite más modificaciones
   - Cuando falla la navegación falla y no navega

   Ninguna de las opciones anteriores hace lo que quieres
3. La opción mas cercana es `redirectTo` pero este, al igual que `template` espera que le retornes un `string` y no una promesa.

   > La función `redirectTo` espera que le retornen un `string` que será usado para actualizar `$location.path()` y `$location.search()`

**Solución**

Haz un nuevo controller y pasale la url a la que debe redireccionar en la query. Luego de 5 segundos redireccionas

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/temporal/:id', {
        template: '<h1>Redireccionando en {{tiempo}} s</h1><div><a href="#/siguiente/3">Navegar ahora</a></div>',
        controller: 'TemporalCtrl'
      })
      .when('/siguiente/:id', {
        template: '<h1>En la siguiente vista el id es {{id}}</h1>',
        controller: 'SiguienteCtrl'
      })
  })
  .controller('TemporalCtrl', function($scope, $interval, $location, $routeParams) {
    var promise;
    $scope.tiempo = 5;

    promise = $interval(function() {
      $scope.tiempo = $scope.tiempo - 1;
      if ($scope.tiempo === 0) {
        $location.url('/siguiente/' + $routeParams.id)
      }
    }, 1000, $scope.tiempo);

    $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
      $interval.cancel(promise);
    });
  })
  .controller('SiguienteCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.id = $routeParams.id;
  })
  .run(function($location, $timeout) {
    $location.url('/temporal/3');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-route.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Algo así es lo que quiero @devconcept, pero en mi caso es una url con id (/siguiente:id) y no una fija (/siguiente). Cómo sería el código entonces? Ejemplo: url:id -> 0s -> plantilla temporal -> 5s -> plantilla final

Comment: @AdrianoJosué Actualizé la respuesta. Básicamente no cambia mucho, solo tienes que pasar el id ya sea en la query o como un parámetro (yo opté por esto último)

Comment: Disculpa que te moleste tanto @devconcept  lol. Parece que no me eh explicado bien, lo único que quiero es que al acceder a una noticia de mi web se ejecute el template temporal y luego de los 5 segundos me redirija a la url que debí aver accedido. Si quieres puedes ver el archivo **app.js** de mi web, no está minificado. [geekmox.com](http://geekmox.com)

Comment: @AdrianoJosué Ese es el punto de mi respuesta. Lo que tienes que hacer es cambiar como compones los links de tus noticias, de hecho ahora con más información ni siquiera necesitas el redirectUrl, simplemente tienes que **cambiar todos los links** a la url `/temporal/:id` (por ejemplo) y como ya tienes el `id` y sabes cual es la url de noticias redirecciona directamente a `/news/:id`. Un controlador con un intervalo como el que te puse hace el truco.

Comment: No eh podido implementarlo no se qué pasa, al acceder desde cualquier url de mi web se activa el "TemporalCtrl" y luego de los 5 segundos se va al template de "/error404" que tengo, también sucede luego de aver dado clic en cualquier noticia y de aver pasado los 5 segundos. Ojalá y pudieras darme un ejemplo, cuando tengas tiempo claro.

Comment: @AdrianoJosué Actualizé el ejemplo. Espero que ahora entiendas mejor. Recuerda lo que te dije de **cambiar todos los links** de tu sitio. Para cancelar la redirección en caso que se navegues antes de que expire el intervalo usa `$inteval.cancel` para cancelar el intervalo en un evento `$destroy` del `$scope`

Comment: Ahora sí eh podido implementarlo correctamente, te agradezco la ayuda @devconcept. ¿Una pregunta, para que se muestre el "template temporal" hay que acceder a "/temporal/id" por ejemplo, pero si accedo a "/news/id" no se muestra, obviamente. hay alguna forma de que si accedo a "/news/id" acceda primero al "template temporal"? Quiero hacerlo así por si alguien comparte el enlace.

Comment: @AdrianoJosué Creo que la única forma de lograrlo es guardando un valor en el localStorage para saber si se ha visitado el temporal de una noticia con id X. Cuando navegues a `/temporal` actualizas el arreglo de ids visitados agregando el id correspondiente y cuando navegues a `/news/id` compruebas que el id se encuentre almacenado. Por cierto de acuerdo a los estándares de Restful no debes usar `/temporal` para nombrar tus urls sino una palabra que tenga algún significado para tus usuarios.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, por cierto en el template de "navegar ahora" tienes `#/siguiente/5` con el 5 hardcodeado.

Comment: @rnd Corregido. No sé como lo pasé por alto. Gracias.

Comment: @devconcept Te agradezco la ayuda. Sobre lo del localStorage me quede así O_O lol, no sabría cómo implementar algo así. Cuando tengas tiempo, si no fuera mucha molestia, te agradecería que actualizaras el ejemplo con lo del localStorage implementado. para yo ver cómo puedo agregarlo a mi proyecto.

Answer (score 1):

Trata con esto a ver:

```
  setTimeout(function () {
  window.location = '/ruta'
  }, 5000);
```