# Cómo mostrar una "Push notification" con push.js una sola vez por usuario con el "localStorage"

Tags: javascript, html5, push-notification

Tengo está push notification automática en el index.html que se muestra cada vez que acceden a mi web, lo que quiero hacer es que con el "localStorage" solo se muestre una vez por usuario y no sea tan molesta. Les agradecería que me dieran un ejemplo de cómo implementarlo.

```html
<script>
  Push.create("¡Aviso de Política de Cookies!", {
    body: "Utilizamos cookies propias y de terceros para mejorar nuestros servicios y mostrarle publicidad relacionada con sus preferencias mediante el análisis de sus hábitos de navegación. Si continua navegando, consideramos que acepta su uso. Puede obtener más información ‘aquí’.",
    icon: 'icon.png',
    timeout: 5000,
    onClick: function () {
        window.location = "/cookies-policy";
        this.close();
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Podrías guardar en `localStorage` simplemente un boolean para indicar que ya fue mostrada. Algo así:

```
var avisoCookiesMostrado = window.localStorage.getItem('avisoCookiesMostrado');
if(!avisoCookiesMostrado) {
    Push.create("¡Aviso de Política de Cookies!", {
        body: "Utilizamos cookies propias y de terceros para mejorar nuestros servicios y mostrarle publicidad relacionada con sus preferencias mediante el análisis de sus hábitos de navegación. Si continua navegando, consideramos que acepta su uso. Puede obtener más información ‘aquí’.",
        icon: 'icon.png',
        timeout: 5000,
        onClick: function () {
            window.location = "/cookies-policy";
            this.close();
        }
    });
    window.localStorage.setItem('avisoCookiesMostrado', true);
}
```

Comment: Eh implementado tu ejemplo y me ha funcionado correctamente, te agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: @AdrianoJosué Pequeño detalle `window.localStorage.getItem` devuelve un string no un booleano. Para eso necesitas `JSON.parse` ten cuidado cuando compares `if(!avisoCookiesMostrado)` ya que `"true"` y `"false"` ambos son `true`. El ejemplo funciona bien pero si alguna vez tienes que setearlo a `false` usa `removeItem` en su lugar.

Comment: @devconcept Gracias por el detalle. No se si ya lo viste, en mi pregunta del ["template temporal"](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18336/ngroute-template-temporal-durante-5-segundos-al-acceder-a-una-ruta-con-id) te eh dejado un comentario molestando un poco más lol, espero que puedas ayudarme.